# Application menu consistency

Tags: wingpanel, user-interface, menu

I'm a longtime macOS user and I discovered recently eOS. I like it for its minimalism and resemblance to macOS, and also because the eOS team seems dedicated to usability a lot. But when I look at the present situation of app menus in eOS I'm perplexed:

- Native eOS apps have no app menu at all.
- Traditional apps have app menus.
- macOS has a global menubar on the top panel.

My question is: **What is the eOS team’s view on this topic?** What's the best usable approach on app menus? We need consistency on the whole system. Maybe eOS should adopt global app menus like macOS?

Answer (score 0):

If elementary OS supported app menus, they would document it in their [Human Interface Guidelines](https://elementary.io/docs/human-interface-guidelines).
App menus are not mentioned specifically but there is documentation on creating toolbars in individual applications.
I infer from the guidelines that elementary OS is focused on other ways of providing consistency which are more intuitive for users than App Menus.
In GNOME there was inconsistency in how apps handled App Menus, which lead to their removal as mentioned in Allan Day's blog post [Farewell, application menus!](https://blogs.gnome.org/aday/2018/10/09/farewell-application-menus/)
Given that, I doubt that App Menus will ever happen but keep an eye on the Human Interface Guidelines in case I'm wrong.
If you would like App Menus in elementary OS, the best way to give such feedback directly to the developers is through *About -> Report Problems*.